# Recovering VCS 2 node cluster in DR?

Tags: linux, cluster, high-availability, data-recovery, disaster-recovery

We are looking for a solution to recover the 2 node VCS Cluster at DR location for a DR Test.

Prod: Hardware is Dell with 24 cores 64 GB RAM with Suse 11.4 Linux over SAN Boot & 4 NIC's of 1 Gig.

DR: HP Hardware with 48 cores 128 GB RAM with Suse 11.4 locally installed on hard drives. (Hardware keeps changing on each DR test but it will be equal or better than prod. 4 NIC's of 1 Gig here as well. OS version will not change it will be exactly the same.

In DR we were facing challenges to recover boot from SAN OS with replicated LUN, we belive those changes are because of change in Hardwear. Hence we installed the OS locally and then got the Boot LUN which we had replicated in DR mounted on the server in /tmp/ , so that we can copy the requried directories and files from that boot lun.

Then used "cp -Rpnv  " command to copy all the files from below directories of boot lun to same directories of newly installed OS directories on local disk drives. (this was done without overwriting existing files from the installed or running OS's directory)

/etc
/home
/opt
/usr
/var
/sbin
Then we took backup of below files and then overwriten those with the once which where there in the boot lun, to match prod environment.

/etc/group
/etc/shadow
/etc/passwd
/etc/hosts
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/security/limits.conf

Then we also setup the local environment using .profile files in root user and the /etc/sktn directories & then reseted the root password. & rebooted the system.

(Note: We are using the same network and VLAN's in DR as they are in Prod. Just the difference is that Prod Network and DR Network are no ware connected.)

after doing all this OS comes up fine we can login and all but the VCS cluster dinies to start and throughts many errors.

Is there a way we can recover the cluster by reinstalling or any other method? (We do not have any backup solution as we have everything on SAN including the OS in PROD and all SAN LUN's are replicated to DR location.) and then just restoring the main.cf & type.cf & llttab files?

Please help!! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Please provide the cluster errors and how you have attempted to fix them. You have described your environment, but not what specifically the problem is.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you did the backup and how you did the restore. It's possible the restored system differs from the original in some way such as file ownership, permissions, non-atomic backup of files changing during the backup.